# Forms and objects in arrays

Tags: php, oop

I am learning OOP in PHP and in an exercise, I don't know how to send form data to objects and enter the objects in an array. I was going through a lot of Youtube tutorials and forums but I couldn't find or understand much.

The exercise first asks for a class to manage the products of a supermarket whose attributes are the numeric key, the description, the price and the stock. It also asks me to define a constructor with parameters as methods.

```
<?php
class Product{

private $key;
private $description;
private $price;
private $stock;

public function __construct($key, $description, $price, $stock){
    $this->key = $key;
    $this->description = $description;
    $this->price = $price;
    $this->stock = $stock;
}
public function setKey($key){
    $this->key = $key;
}
public function getKey(){
    return $this->key;
}
public function setDescription($description){
    $this->description = $description;
}
public function getDescription(){
    return $this->description;
}
public function setPrice($price){
    $this->price = $price;
}
public function getPrice(){
    return $this->price;
}
public function setStock($stock){
    $this->stock = $stock;
}
public function getStock(){
    return $this->stock;
}
}
```

Then it asks me to use that class to declare an array of objects and control an inventory of up to 50 products using the POST method. In addition this program must have a menu with the next items: Add product, Remove product, List product, Sort product by key number and Exit.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
      <label for="key">Enter product key</label></br>
      <input type="number" name="key" id="key" required></br>

      <label for="description">Enter product description</label></br>
      <input type="text" name="description" id="description" required></br>

      <label for="price">Enter product price</label></br>
      <input type="text" name="price" id="price" required></br>

      <label for="stock">Enter the stock of the product</label></br>
      <input type="number" name="stock" id="stock" required></br>

      <button type="submit" name="add" id="add">Add product</button>
      <button type="submit" name="baja" id="baja">Remove product</button>
      <button type="submit" name="list" id="list">List product</button>
      <button type="submit" name="Sort" id="Sort">Sort product</button>
      <button type="submit" name="exit" id="exit">Exit</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the problem: I don't know how to insert the object in the array without deleting the previous ones and I don't know how to print all the entered objects.

```
<?php
if (strlen(session_id()) < 1) {
session_start();
}
include_once("product.php");

if(isset($_POST["add"])){
   $_SESSION["quantity"] = $_SESSION["quantity"] +1;
   $quantity = $_SESSION["quantity"];
   if($quantity<=50){
      $oproduct = new Product($_POST["key"], $_POST["description"], $_POST["price"], 
      $_POST["stock"]);
      $oproduct->setKey($_POST["key"]);
      $oproduct->setDescription($_POST["description"]);
      $oproduct->setPrice($_POST["price"]);
      $oproduct->setStock($_POST["stock"]);
      $_SESSION["prod"]= $oproduct;
      print_r($_SESSION["prod"]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dynamically append `[]` a new product to the array:

```
$_SESSION["prod"][] = $oproduct;
```

Or you could use `key` if it is unique:

```
$_SESSION["prod"][$_POST["key"]] = $oproduct;
```

Also, it looks like you have already added the info here:

```
$oproduct = new Product($_POST["key"], $_POST["description"], $_POST["price"], $_POST["stock"]);
```

So why are you doing this?

```
  $oproduct->setKey($_POST["key"]);
  $oproduct->setDescription($_POST["description"]);
  $oproduct->setPrice($_POST["price"]);
  $oproduct->setStock($_POST["stock"]);
```